# Use of the verb reflect

Tags: verbs

Is it okay to use the verb 'reflect' in an imperative sentence to mean 'apply'?

The document reflects the changes that were made.

To use the verb for the same meaning as above, can you say

'Reflect the changes in the document.'?

I found on the Internet this sentence: "On how to manage the general debate more effectively and in a more focused manner, I will try to reflect every suggestion and comment." daccess-ods.un.org

Can a person 'reflect' changes in a document, etc.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, my usage of reflected would need to be to include two entities:

1. The **suggested** or **planned** changes to the document or content of the document.
2. The actual document.

Hence forming a sentence such as "the suggested changes have been reflected in the new document", or something along these lines.

Hopefully this helps answer your question.